Flutter Not Printing to Console for Specific Button
Just wanted to increase awareness of this potential confusing mistake. This question is a bit of a misnomer, because there isn't anything wrong with the Flutter printing mechanism.
Printing to the console is one of the first things many developers would try to do to investigate this, but the print will also not execute. Debug breakpoints also will not be hit.
See anything wrong with the following code that would prevent it from printing to the console? It is valid syntax and will compile just fine.
TextButton(
          child: Text("Press me"),
          onPressed: () => () {
            debugPrint("I printed to the debug console!");
          },
        ),


Replace your onPressed method with onPressed: () {
debugPrint("I printed to the debug console!");
}. The onPressed should directly reference the function body instead of defining a new function.

Solution
The issue with the original code comes down to confusion between an expression body and a block body. A function is being passed to the expression body, instead of defining the function.
So when onPressed executes the code after => it only executes defining a block body. In fact, you could make it work by adding () to the end of the curly braces since that would be calling the block body after it is defined, but that is a bit of a Rube Goldberg machine. The better solutions are listed below; either of the following are valid ways to write this.
Expression body (a shortcut syntax, normally a single line),
You put what you want to execute (the definition) right after the =>
TextButton(
          child: Text("Press me"),
          onPressed: () => debugPrint("I printed to the debug console!"),
        ),

Block body (usually multiple lines involved)
You put what you want to execute (the definition) inside curly braces that contain the multiple lines each ending with semicolons.
TextButton(
          child: Text("Press me"),
          onPressed: () { debugPrint("I printed to the debug console!"); },
        ),

